# How to insert selected items from a listview into a database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a number of textboxes and 4 listviews. Each listview contains a number of options. The user enters in some data to the textboxes and selects any number of options from the listviews. All of this is then inserted into a row in a database. At the moment I am gathering all selected options from each listview and joining them together in a String, one string for each list and inserting the concatenated string.

```
    'retrieve reference type 1s selected
    For i = 0 To listRef3.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        selectedRef3.Add(listRef3.CheckedItems(i).Text)
    Next
    'join array contents into one delimited string to be added to the database
    refType3 = String.Join(",", selectedRef3.ToArray())
```

However this makes retrieval of individual selections from the listview tricky as I would like to be able to filter a different database based on the selections at a later date.

Is it possible to create an insert statement that will add each listview selection to a particular column in the database dynamically as the user may select any number of items from the list?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Have you tried it yet?  Do you have any code that tries to connect to the database?

Comment: Yes I have tried. My insert statement was insert into ListTable ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5, ref6 VALUES (@ref1,@ref2,@ref3,@ref3,@ref4,@ref5, @ref6) But the user can select any number of options so I do not know how to construct my insert statement to allow insertion of any number of items between 1 and 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to construct the needed statement by building on your existing join statement just a little bit (I assume the text you are getting from your checked items is like "ref1", etc.  Have I understood you correctly?).

```
Dim cols, vals, insertStatement As String

cols = String.Join(", ", selectedRef3.ToArray())
vals = "@" & String.Join(", @", selectedRef3.ToArray())

insertStatement = "insert into ListTable (" & cols & ") VALUES (" & vals & ")"
```

Apologies if there are any mistakes; my VB is a bit rusty.